# Java: renameTo() function failing

Tags: java

Java

The code below was written to read all files in, and send the data to another method (setOutput()), and then call a method to rename the last read file to another directory, and then delete the original.  Everything seems to work up until the smdrCleanup() method is called.  The renameTo() is failing.

From what I understand, if a FileReader is wrapped in a BufferedReader, I only need to call BufferedReader.close() to release the last read file... which I am doing here.

I have also seen where if the file were still "open", being scanned by anti-virus programs, or otherwise locked by a process, the renameTo() function would fail.  I have used Process Explorer to review what may have it locked, and I don't see anything locking it.

I have my method setup to throw any kind of IOExceptions, but I am not getting any exceptions.  Everything runs, but the console merely says that the file was not copied.

I am running Eclipse Helios Release 2, Windows 7 Ultimate, local administrator, UAC disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void smdrReader(String path, String oldPath) throws IOException
{
  output = null; //nullify the value of output to avoid duplicate data
  File folder = new File(path); //setting the directory for raw data files
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); //array of files within the folder/directory

  //For loop to iterate through the available files, open, & read contents to String Buffer.
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) //verifying next entry in array is a file
      {
          File fileName = new File(listOfFiles[i].getName());//getting file name from array iteration
          StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(2048);//establishing StringBuffer for reading file contents into
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + fileName));//reader to actually access/read file
          String readData = String.valueOf(reader);//String variable being set to value of the reader
          fileData.append(readData);//appending data from String variable into StringBuffer variable
          setOutput(fileData);//setting the value of "output" to the value of StringBuffer
          fileData.delete(0, i);
          reader.close();//closing the reader (closing the file)
          smdrCleanup(oldPath,fileName.toString());//calling method to move processed file and delete original
      }

  }

}

//method to rename input file into another directory and delete the original file to avoid duplicate processing
public void smdrCleanup(String oldPathPassed, String fileNamePassed) throws IOException   
{
   File oldFile = new File(oldPathPassed);//establishing File object for path to processed folder
   File fileName = new File(fileNamePassed);//establishing File object for the fileName to rename/delete
   String oldFilePath = oldFile.toString();
   boolean success = fileName.renameTo(new File(oldFilePath + "\\" + fileName + ".old"));//attempting to rename file
    if (!success) //checking the success of the file rename operation
    {
        System.out.println("The File Was NOT Successfully Moved!");//reporting error if the file cannot be renamed
    }
        else
        {
            fileName.delete();//deleting the file if it was successfully renamed
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`oldFile.toString();` returns the full path of the file including its file name, so if your old file path is **c:\path\to\file.txt**, `oldFilePath + "\\" + fileName + ".old"` will be **c:\path\to\file.txt\file.txt.old**.

Since there is no folder **c:\path\to\file.txt**, it fails. change it to

```
boolean success = fileName.renameTo(new File(oldFilePath + ".old"));
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  I made the changes, and debugged the application, and the "fileName" variable has a value of "New Text Document.txt".... no path.  Any other ideas?  I still find it odd that I am getting NO exceptions when it fails.  That is what is making me think it is something related to my code logic than an IO issue.

Comment: Use getAbsolutePath to get the full path of the file

Comment: MByD,  I don't want to get the full path.  I want to renameTo() the current file to a NEW path, but I am getting failures with no exceptions to point me in the direction of the problem.  I am able to write to the primary directory of application in another part of the app, so I don't think it's a permission issue.  Being so green in Java, I just don't know what it could be... especially without exceptions.

Comment: print the path before you create a new file and see if it is a valid path.

Answer (score 1):

[File.renameTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) can fail for any number of reasons:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this
>   method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename
>   operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another,
>   it might not be atomic, and it might
>   not succeed if a file with the
>   destination abstract pathname already
>   exists. The return value should always
>   be checked to make sure that the
>   rename operation was successful.

But there's not much feedback on why it fails. Before calling renameTo, verify that the file you're moving exists, and the parent directory you are moving it to also exists, and `canWrite()`. Are these on the same disk volume? If not, it might fail.

**EDIT: Code sample added **

Try something like the following. Modifications:

1. Accepts File objects instead of Strings
2. Uses 2-arg File constructor to create a child File object in a parent directory
3. Better error checking

This might give you some clues into what is failing.

```
public void smdrCleanup(File oldPathPassed, File fileNamePassed) throws IOException {
    if (!oldPathPassed.exists() || !oldPathPassed.isDirectory() || !oldPathPassed.canWrite() ) throw new IOException("Dest is not a writable directory: " + oldPathPassed);
    if (!fileNamePassed.exists()) throw new IOException("File does not exist: " + fileNamePassed);
    final File dest = new File(oldPathPassed, fileNamePassed + ".old");
    if (dest.exists()) throw new IOException("File already exists: " + dest);
    boolean success = (fileNamePassed).renameTo(dest);//attempting to rename file
    if (!success) //checking the success of the file rename operation
    {
        throw new IOException("The File Was NOT Successfully Moved!");
    } else {
        // file was successfully renamed, no need to delete
    }
}
```

Comment: It is on the same disk volume right now, but if someone else wanted to use this application, that might not be the case.  I'll try your recommendation and see what I get.  Thanks!!

Comment: According to the boolean "canWrite()" method, the directory can be written to... but it won't.  I'm still not getting any errors/exceptions.  I'm SOOO confused.

Comment: File.renameTo() won't ever throw an IOException, it will just return false. Does the file you're renaming to already exist? Is there a file lock involved? Can you write to a file with a slightly different name?